# Can access main URL and Dashboard but not any posts or pages

Tags: user-access

I'm not sure what happened. But this week I suddenly lost access to the pages and posts of this URL: www.michaelfstewart.com

GoDaddy had notified me of some files to delete as they were suspicious. I did so, but pretty sure I still had access to those pages after that.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be an issue with `permalink` or `htacces` file. try to reset permalinks to default and check.

Comment: Thanks, you got it. Godaddy had flagged my .htaccess file as malware. I restored it. Done.

Comment: Ok great, can you mark this ans as correct if this help you ?